# Error in IDE on loading custom component. Delphi bug or my mistake?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I found a strange issue with a custom component that creates/destroys subcomponents dynamically.

```
type
  TPanelTest = class(TPanel)
  private
    FShowPanel : Boolean;
    FPanel : TPanel;
    function GetShowPanel: Boolean;
    procedure SetShowPanel(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure CreateSubPanel;
    procedure DestroySubPanel;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property ShowPanel : Boolean read GetShowPanel write SetShowPanel;
  end;

...

{ TPanelTest }
constructor TPanelTest.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  SetBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);
  ShowPanel := True;
end;

procedure TPanelTest.CreateSubPanel;
begin
  if not Assigned(FPanel) then
  begin
    FPanel := TPanel.Create(Self);
    with FPanel do
    begin
      SetSubComponent(True);
      Parent := Self;
      Caption := '';
      Top := 0;
      Left := 0;
      Height := 50;
      Align := alTop;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TPanelTest.DestroySubPanel;
begin
  if Assigned(FPanel) then
    FreeAndNil(FPanel);
end;

function TPanelTest.GetShowPanel: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FShowPanel;
end;

procedure TPanelTest.SetShowPanel(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  FShowPanel := Value;
  if Value then
    CreateSubPanel
  else
    DestroySubPanel;
end;
```

In run-time and design-time, everything (creating and destroying `FPanel`) works correct, but if I set `ShowPanel` to False, then save the project, close and open it again, I get an error:

> Error creating form: Access violation at address 50CF4B9C in module 'vcl270.bpl'. Read of address 00000000.

If I manually change `ShowPanel` to True in the `.dfm` file, everything starts work correct again.

So, what am I missing? I'm using Delphi 10.4.2 CE

For now, I use a workaround with making `SubPanel` invisible instead of destroying it, but I want to make this right.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you set Showpanel to false, when you open the form, ```SetShowPanel``` tries to run ```DestroySubPanel```; but FPanel was never created and so (iiuic), accessing ```FPanel``` chokes.   Been some time since I've touched Delphi...

Comment: @ewokx No, I checked with simple logging - it creates `FPanel` when setting `ShowPanel` to True in constructor. On second step Delphi set properties from dfm and after that I get error. But I can't catch where error appears. And as I said when I play with setting `ShowPanel` to false and back to true runtime and design time (from object inspector) - everything is ok.

Comment: @Capricorn7B FYI, since you are setting `ShowPanel=True` in the constructor, you should add `default True` to the declaration of the `ShowPanel` property, eg: `property ShowPanel : Boolean read GetShowPanel write SetShowPanel default True;` Otherwise the DFM will think the default is False instead. Also, you don't need to check `Assigned()` before calling `FreeAndNil()`, it already handles that internally. Also, when you have design-time errors like this, you can run a 2nd instance of the IDE to debug the 1st instance so you can step through your code *at design-time*.

Comment: @Capricorn7B for future reference, please don't edit your questions to post solutions. That is what posting answers is meant for instead. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, I thought that I save other people's time this way. I won't do that again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `SetSubComponent(True)`:

> ...Unlike top-level components, subcomponents are not saved with the form or data module in which they reside. Instead, a subcomponent appears as the value of a published property of its Owner, and its published properties and events are saved in the form file with the owning component.

In this case, I don't need to set `FPanel` as a SubComponent of `TPanelTest`.

Comment: You should call `SetSubComponent(True)` only when you are creating a `TComponent`-derived object in the constructor that needs to appear as a nested property in the Object Inspector. Otherwise, don't call it. That is not the case here.

Comment: Yes, I got it. That's why I quoted text from manual in answer